# Http Request Error when C# Project Target to .Net Framework 4.8 in Window 7

Tags: httprequest, .net-4.8

My C# Project Target .Net Framework 4.6.1 before, and working fine in window 7,8.1, and 10. But now I changed my target framework to .Net Framework 4.8, Window 8.1, and 10 still no problem but window 7 error in HTTP Request.

```
"An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://Test.123.com/API/ServiceRouter.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."
```

**Remark**:

1. The Http Request Action is just receive some Data from my service
2. .Net Framework 4.8 already installed in window 7 (SP 1) platform.
3. Nothing changed to code at all

Comment: I found the issue, and this is because TLS1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 as the default in .NET Framework 4.7. Starting with .NET Framework 4.7.1, defaults to the operating system configured version. So I need to add this code before HTTP request.

  "System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;""   
 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Answer (score 0):

Great *Chau Chun*. This code solved my problem:

```
"System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;"
```

Thanks.